# How to pack a dll file

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm trying to "pack" a dll file into a file that contains other resources. I'm reading the bytes of the DLL and writnig them back in the "package" file, but when I unpack everything, the DLL is corruped.

I can see that I'm writing the "package" file incorrectly ( input is 8kb - output is 9kb and dll is not working ) and I can't seem to get why this is happening.

I read the bytes from the input file, put them into memorystream via binarywriter and then write them to the "package" file using File.WriteAllBytes.

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDest[i]);
```

---

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms);

            bw.Write(count); //int32
            bw.Write(version); //int32

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                bw.Write(lengthofbytes);
                bw.Write(someinfo); // string
                bw.Write(filecontents); // bytes
            }

            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes("some.dll", bytes);
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is combine a bunch of files in one file and then "unpack" them where they need to be. Unfortunately one of the files has to be a .DLL

Comment: why don´t you use a zip file? There are also libraries for .NET that support zipping of files. See [dotnetzip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Do you mean merge dll files?

Comment: I can use libs that are currently in Mono and I don't think that dotnetzip is supported by mono. And I don't mean merge dll files, because I have all kind of different files.

Comment: How do you read back the package? Particulary the `someinfo` string?
Please provide the unpacking code.

Comment: I'm loading the file in a memory stream and reading from it with binaryreader... But this is not the case. I tryed to read and write the dll and it is corupped. I mean I have this code:

    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(thedll);
    File.WriteAllBytes("output.dll", bytes);